# Android firebase UNAUTHENTICATED error after user was idle for about an 30 min

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm building a multi chatrooms app. Inside the chatroom Activity i have few registered listeners (That are added/removed depends if Activity is on running state or not). 
The user is always logged in (if didn't requested to log out).

When user is minimizing the app for an about 30 minutes and returns, I register all listeners back but no data is returned and this exception is thrown:

```
.889 6473-6518/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( yhKHCsi997gYU9qcCSzGI8NJxU92 ).
2019-08-29 03:22:16.894 6473-6586/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/Firestore: (20.2.0) [FirestoreCallCredentials]: Failed to get token: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: getToken aborted due to token change.
2019-08-29 03:22:16.909 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: UNAUTHENTICATED
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Util.exceptionFromStatus(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@20.2.0:121)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.FirestoreChannel.exceptionFromStatus(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@20.2.0:273)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.FirestoreChannel.access$100(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@20.2.0:42)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.FirestoreChannel$3.onClose(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@20.2.0:202)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:700)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:399)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:500)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:65)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:592)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$700(ClientCallImpl.java:508)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:632)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$DelayedStartFactory.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@20.2.0:205)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err: Caused by: io.grpc.StatusException: UNAUTHENTICATED
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at io.grpc.Status.asException(Status.java:541)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Util.exceptionFromStatus(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@20.2.0:119)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.910 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:    ... 25 more
2019-08-29 03:22:16.911 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err: Caused by: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: getToken aborted due to token change
2019-08-29 03:22:16.911 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.firestore.auth.FirebaseAuthCredentialsProvider.lambda$getToken$1(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@20.2.0:94)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.911 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.firestore.auth.FirebaseAuthCredentialsProvider$$Lambda$2.then(Unknown Source:4)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.911 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.run(Unknown Source:5)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.911 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.911 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.911 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.911 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.911 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.911 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
2019-08-29 03:22:16.911 6473-6473/com.dev.dnlgby.connectaround W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

What could be the reason?
Do I need to refresh tokens somehow?

Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't look like a thrown exception.  That's a series of warning messages (note the "W" on each line).  Warnings are not errors.  What exactly is malfunctioning in your app?  Do you have code to share?  Something specific?

Comment: That prevents me from getting data from the registered listeners. this is an exception i am getting when registering. What is the meaning to UNAUTHENTICATED? something to do with the refresh and ID tokens?

Comment: Posted the full stacktrace.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything to refresh a token.  That all happens automatically.  Make sure your SDKs are all up to date, and if this still happens, contact Firebase support with your full instructions to reproduce the problem.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Ok, Thank you. now using the latest versions of Firebase. I will update.

Comment: After updating to firebase auth version to "19.0.0", the problem is solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After updating to firebase auth version to "19.0.0", the problem is solved. Thanks